# Select published topics

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, topic, openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using the  openni_camera and openni_launch stacks with ROS fuerte on a platform with low processing power.

I only need two topics: /rgb/image_rect and /depth_registered/image_rect. Is there a way to only publish those topics in order to speed up the processing time?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93641/select-published-topics/) by [Pino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4831/pino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not have to do that in ROS. Data will (should) be computed only if there is at least one subscriber listening to your topic.
The whole goal here is to reduce the configuration burden of each node. Think of the topic list as a list of capabilities and not a list of produced data.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-01**:
Is there a way to get topics from more than one Kinect?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-01**:
I guess if you launch the nodes twice in different namespaces it should work. You may need to connect your two kinects on two different USB controllers though.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-03**:
Well as I explained in my question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/96071/accessing-multiple-kinects-in-ros-hydro/ I'm not sure exactly how to modify the launch file to launch separate nodes. Any ideas?

Edit: Thanks for the suggestion Thomas, it helped me figure it out.